# Incrementally adding 15 sec to time in CSS @each loop

Tags: html, css, animation

I am adapting a CSS script that repetitively performs an animation task, but instead of repeating a segment of code 30 times, I placed it in a loop. In this case there are 30 `<div></div>` segments and the CSS performs the animation for each:

```
@each $i from 1 through 30 

#dna div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: -59.85s;
}
#dna div:nth-child(#{$i})::before {
    animation-delay: -59.85s;
}
#dna div:nth-child(#{$i})::after {
    animation-delay: -59.85s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateX(359deg);
    }
}
```

The problem is I need to be able to add 15 sec to the -59.85 sec with each loop. I am not sure where to start since I never used CSS with this capacity.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with variables etc in css but I've found that `calc()` should be able to help you.

Try this:

```
#dna div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: calc(-59.85s + $i * 30);
}
#dna div:nth-child(#{$i})::before {
    animation-delay: calc(-59.85s + $i * 30);
}
#dna div:nth-child(#{$i})::after {
    animation-delay: calc(-59.85s + $i * 30);
}
```

For more 'programming' functionality of css check: [this source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_functions.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can do your loops in scss files likes this:

```
$fade-delay: -59.85; // start value, adjust to get value of your choice in first loop
$fade-delay-seconds-to-add: 15; // seconds as pure number to add in each loop
$number-of-loops: 30;

@for $i from 1 through $number-of-loops {

    $fade-delay: $fade-delay + $fade-delay-seconds-to-add;

    #dna div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        animation-delay: #{$fade-delay}s;
    }
    #dna div:nth-child(#{$i})::before {
        animation-delay: #{$fade-delay}s;
    }
    #dna div:nth-child(#{$i})::after {
        animation-delay: #{$fade-delay}s;
    }
}
```

Sass then compiles that to:

```
#dna div:first-child,
#dna div:first-child:after,
#dna div:first-child:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay:-44.85s;
    animation-delay:-44.85s
}

#dna div:nth-child(2),
#dna div:nth-child(2):after,
#dna div:nth-child(2):before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -29.85s;
    animation-delay:-29.85s;
}

#dna div:nth-child(3),
#dna div:nth-child(3):after,
#dna div:nth-child(3):before {
    -webkit-animation-delay:-14.85s;
    animation-delay:-14.85s
}

/* ... and so on */
```